# cuda group by and atomic counters

Tags: cuda, atomic

I have an unordered array of labelled elements :

```
[0,1,0,2,0,1,2] // labels only
```

Which I want to sort:

```
[0,0,0,1,1,2,2]
```

I already have counted how many elements are labelled with each label and reduced as an array of offsets:

```
[0,3,5]
```

meaning I know that I need to store all 0-labelled elements starting at position 0, 1-labelled elements starting at position 3 and so on.

```
template<typename T>
__global__ void GroupBy(T* output, T* input, int count, int* offsets) {
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    T elem = input[index];
    output[offsets[elem.label]] = elem; // problem here
    atomicAdd(offsets[label], 1);
}
```

However, read write operation before the atomicAdd is not atomic, so I have memory race-condition. 
I would not have that for a single counter, since

```
int count = 0;
atomicAdd(&count, 1);
output[count] = elem;
```

would indeed yield me a unique counter per thread.

How can I solve that issue and have a dynamic array of atomic counters?

Comment: Your use of atomicAdd is incorrect in the both cases (the second is also a race). It returns the previous value when an atomic update is applied, so reverse the atomicAdd and assignment operations (the later using the return value of the atomicAdd) and your problem disappears

Comment: Damn thank you. Was not thinking about the return value of atomicAdd. Shame on me

Comment: NP. Would you like to add a short answer yourself? There is probably a duplicate for this somewhere too, but a self answer will get this off the unaswered queue

Comment: Yes I just did. I didn't really find the appropriate duplicate (which is why I asked the question in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the kind reminder of talonmies about the return value of atomicAdd, I've beed able to fix my kernel to this:

```
template<typename T>
__global__ void GroupBy(T* output, T* input, int count, int* offsets) {
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    T elem = input[index];
    int oldOffset = atomicAdd(&offsets[elem.label], 1);
    output[oldOffset] = elem; 
}
```

Indeed, atomicAdd atomically increments what's stored at first argument, and returns the old value:

> [atomicAdd(address, val)] reads the 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit word old located at the address
>   address in global or shared memory, computes (old + val), and stores
>   the result back to memory at the same address. These three operations
>   are performed in one atomic transaction. The function returns old.

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicadd

Comment: you have a typo, atomicAdd needs an address as first argument